# Importing "@daily-co/daily-js" into SvelteKit app throws "global is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite, sveltekit

**What I tried:**

1. I tried work around it via `if (browser)`, more specifically{
   `if (!browser) { let DailyIframe = await import('daily-co/daily-js) }` in the load function inside `<script context="module">` ) so the code is always executed on the server). Then pass it as a prop to a component. However, although it worked on the server, the local dev environment re-runs the load function (which has to return an empty prop as it never imported anything) and overrides DailyIframe's value (might be a bug with Vite/SvelteKit).
2. I tried to import the library in an end-point e.g. `api.json.js` instead, which is *always* executed on the server. However, it has to return a json, and I can't pass an entire library variable onto it.

**After research**
It seems like a combination of problems from Vite, SvelteKit and certain libraries where `global` is undefined: [SvelteKit With MongoDB ReferenceError: global is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69171641/sveltekit-with-mongodb-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined))

But I cannot use his solution of putting it in an endpoint, because I need the DailyIframe and the mic audio stream from the client to create a video conference room

Also, why would certain libraries Daily (and looking at other related Stackoverflow posts, MongoDB) throw this error in the first place, while other libraries are safe to use?

Anyway suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

> Why ?

Vite doesn't include shims for Node builtins variables.

Read suggestion to understand:

- https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/728
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-369578814

> Anyway suggestion is appreciated!

In `index.html` add :

```html
<script>
  var global = global || window;
</script>
```

then for example in `App.svelte` :

```html
<script>
import { onMount } from 'svelte'
import DailyIframe from '@daily-co/daily-js'
    
onMount(async () => {
  let callObject = DailyIframe.createFrame()
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
  recorder.start()
})
</script>
```

### Demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltekit-1yn6pz?devtoolsheight=33

> logs preview

[image: logs preview of the room connection]

Comment: Thanks - binding global = window, or importing with CDN worksaround the issue! 
"Some libraries incorrectly rely on node globals being available because they expect to be built in node, but to run in the browser. " - paraphrased from your reading suggestions

Comment: This didn't work for me. I found another solution (that also didn't work) here:
https://dev.to/richardbray/how-to-fix-the-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined-error-in-sveltekitvite-2i49

Comment: @EricDelaCruz I added a demo to the answer,  open it and  then check the console, you will see a lot of errors comming from the call which try to connect to a innexistant room.