# 500 error on SvelteKit deploy to Cloudflare pages

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, cloudflare-pages

When deploying my SvelteKit app to Cloudflare Pages, it builds without issue but navigating to the site shows my navbar and footer, with an error message of `global is not defined`.

In the console, I get the message `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ().`

Solutions like defining global in the index.html or configuring Vite to define it did not work either. These two resources did not prove to be effective, [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70222804/importing-daily-co-daily-js-into-sveltekit-app-throws-global-is-not-defined) and [two](https://dev.to/richardbray/how-to-fix-the-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined-error-in-sveltekitvite-2i49).

My understanding is that this error can occur when there are nodejs (cjs) libraries or code trying to run in a non-node environment, however the app seemed to work perfectly when deploying to other JAMstack platforms. The build preview also worked on my machine. This leads me to believe it's a Cloudflare Pages related issue, though it seems more probable that it's a framework error somehow.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, global was called in one of the dependencies I used. Removing it solved the issue.